# Better alternative to assign SQL results

Tags: sql, python-3.x

The code I have written grabs the list of students in a major, and assigns how many students are enrolled for each major for that year.

```
Format of SQL TABLE: |count(int)|School(var)|Code(var)|Concentration(var)|
```

What is a better alternative for me to assign sql result values to a python variable. Right now I have hard coded the values using IF statements testing to see if they match the name. If it does I then assign the sql value in the first column to a variable. This works right now because I know where everything is... but it will not work if a row was added or removed from my table.

Is there a way I can modify this code to work without it being dependent on the row as it is currently.

```
def grabmajorStartcc():
    sql = ("SELECT count ([2015F Hist].Spridenspriden_ID) AS COUNT, [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 as School, [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_MAJR_CODE_1 as Code, [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_MAJR_CODE_CONC_1 as concentration "
            "FROM [2015F Hist] "
            "WHERE [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1 IN ( 'CC', 'CO', 'LA', 'SB', 'SI', 'SM') "
            "AND [2015F Hist].Cohort_desc = '2015 Fall First Time Trad' "
            "GROUP BY [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1, [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_MAJR_CODE_1, [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_MAJR_CODE_CONC_1 "
            "ORDER BY  [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_COLL_CODE_1, [2015F Hist].SGBSTDNSGBSTDN_MAJR_CODE_1")
    cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    if(result[0][3] == 'CMGD'):
        grabmajorStartcc.cmgd = result[0][0]
    if (result[1][3] == 'CMSD'):
        grabmajorStartcc.cmsd = result[1][0]
    if (result[2][3] == 'ITSS'):
        grabmajorStartcc.itss = result[2][0]
    if (result[3][3] == 'ITST'):
        grabmajorStartcc.itst = result[3][0]
    if (result[4][2] == 'MAAM'):
        grabmajorStartcc.maam = result[4][0]
    if (result[5][2] == 'MATE'):
        grabmajorStartcc.mate = result[5][0]
    if (result[6][2] == 'MATH'):
        grabmajorStartcc.math = result[6][0]
```

Comment: What are those properties of `grabmajorStartcc.*`? In fact is is the same name as the function. There is an easier way but it is not clear what you are trying to do in the end. Also, please post a few rows of current data results as well as desired structure.

Comment: grabmajorStartcc.** is simply me putting the results into a variable function that will allow me to call it outside the function.

Comment: Please post current output. I am seeing you check names across different columns. And with an aggregate query of multiple groupings, likely you may be overwriting values in current loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using dictionaries where keys would be the query's grouping values, *CMGD*, *CMSD*, *ITSS*... and values would be the aggregate *Count*. Below runs dictionary comprehensions, one for *concentration* and other for *major_code* on the cursor row fetch.

```
def grabmajorStartcc():

    sql = ...

    cur.execute(sql)
    result = cur.fetchall()

    grabmajorStartcc.concentration = {row[3]:row[0] for row in result}
    # grabmajorStartcc.concentration['CMGD'] 
    # grabmajorStartcc.concentration['CMSD'] 
    # ...

    grabmajorStartcc.major_code = {row[2]:row[0] for row in result}
    # grabmajorStartcc.major_code['MAAM']     
    # grabmajorStartcc.major_code['MATE']  
    # ...
```

Comment: this might work... can you please explain the code further?

Comment: Basically, instead of separate hard defined function variables, code now uses function dictionaries that change with values. Did you try it? If it does not work, it may be due to *how* you use this method.